# Compare two collections for being equal (same entries, same order) using Stream API, Lambdas etc. in Java

Tags: java, collections, lambda, comparison, java-stream

I googled some SO examples, but they only regard Java 1.7. I'd like to implement it using verion 8 features. Is there some kind of best practice or even ready method to do this? I couldn't fine any. So far for two collections given (var names 'first' and 'second') I can only think of sth. like this:

```
first.forEach(first -> first.equals(second));
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
The two types of collections I try to compare are Set and Collection itself.

Comment: `first.equals(second)`? What are your specific collections?

Comment: Could you show us examples of what collections you are trying to compare?

Comment: What is “Collection itself”?

Comment: `Set` has no order, nor has a `Collection`. There is no reason for a `Set` to have the same order as _itself_ - i.e. iteration order can change. What you are asking makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to compare if both the values and order are the same you can just use `.equals()` :

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3, 4, 5);

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2));
System.out.println(list1.equals(list3));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: The issue arises, I suppose, when you have a `List` and a `Set`. That does beg the question of what "same order" means in that case obviously. The OP needs to elaborate on requirements.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that is true, I will adjust my answer if his requirements become more clear.